# printing multiple lines of renderText in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to get two lines of reactive values printed in the mainpage using two sequential calls to the renderText function. I am now only seeing the second value.

If I remove the second renderText function, the program happily prints the first value, but if I return the second renderText function to the code, the first value is not printed and the second one is.

What I would like is a mainpage with the two reactive values (sensitivity and specificity) displayed; once this is working then I'll throw up some  additional plots.

Is this the wrong render* function, or perhaps the wrong pageWithSidebar() function?

Here are the UI.R and server.R files.

```
#ui.R

library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Header"),
  mainPanel("Main"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("sensitivity",
                  "Sensitivity",
                  min = 0.0,
                  max = 1.0,
                  value = 0.8),
       sliderInput("specificity",
               "Specificity",
               min = 0.0,
               max = 1.0,
               value = 0.4)
    ),


    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel({
      textOutput("caption1")
      textOutput("caption2")
    })
  )
 )
)


and server.R

#server.R

library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$caption1 <- renderText(input$sensitivity)
    output$caption2 <- renderText(input$specificity)
}
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in your call to `mainPanel()` is slightly off.

To fix it, use this

```
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel(
  textOutput("caption1"),
  textOutput("caption2")
)
```

instead of this

```
# Show a plot of the generated distribution
mainPanel({
  textOutput("caption1")
  textOutput("caption2")
})
```

The problem with your version is that in R, whenever an expression enclosed in braces is evaluated, only the result of the final statement in it is returned. You can see that this is more generally the case by trying something like this:

```
{5
 6
 9}
# [1] 9
```

Comment: Many thanks! Two errors.. use of {} and failure to include , between first and second textOutput() calls.

Comment: @user2292410 Glad that helped. If an answer here solves your question, please accept it. That way others will know it's been solved. Alternatively, if it doesn't, let us know how it fails so that folks can dig a little deeper. (To accept, just click the check mark that appears next to an answer. You can also upvote if you like (using the upward pointing arrow), though that's less important.)